# htaccess 301 redirect for webshop transfer

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I searched stackoverflow but couldn't find a solution that fits my need. On top of it, if must admit, that regex is a pretty difficult thing for me. So here is the thing:

I have a new webshop (domain-new.com) that has basically the same products of old shop (weird product urls, weird categories, everything weird, ...) but on a new technology, new domain and proper URLs. Thus, I would like to close the old shop and transfer the SEO rankings with a 301 redirect to the new domain/shop.

My solution is that the old shop/domain serves a .htaccess file with a lot of links:

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 / http://www.domain-new.com/ ###front page
Redirect 301 old-weird-product-path1 http://www.domain-new.com/new-product1.html
Redirect 301 old-weird-product-path2 http://www.domain-new.com/new-product2.html
Redirect 301 old-weird-product-path3 http://www.domain-new.com/new-product3.html
Redirect 301 old-weird-product-path4 http://www.domain-new.com/new-product4.html
```

I could manage to link about 300 products and categories but can't manage to do the hole list of 5000 products and categories.

Is there a way to add a line of code that says: "and for everything else, thats not listed above, redirect to the front page of the new webshop?

Thanks in advance and sorry, if the question was answered somewhere else. I couldn't find the proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

This may be possible with regex match if you have a common pattern in weird urls. 
Then Regex not match common url pattern and redirect to home page of new website something like

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule [^old-weird-product-path] http://www.domain-new.com/ [R=301,L]
```

You may have to refine it as per url structure.

Comment: unfortunately, there is no pattern in the old URLs. So the statement has to be something like: "If not one of the URLs above, redirect to http://domain-new.com/